# How can I dynamically change an Ansible variable?

Tags: ansible

I have this in vars:

```
var1: "test1"
var2: "test2"
var3: "{{var1}}"
```

Now I want to dynamically change `var3: "{{var2}}"`.

I can assign `var3: "test2"`. But how can I assign `var3: "{{var2}}"`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My attempt at the interpretation of the phrase "dynamically change Ansible variable" based on your question:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    var1: "test1"
    var2: "test2"
    var3: "{{var1}}"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=var3
    - set_fact:
        var3: "{{var2}}"
    - debug: var=var3
```

Regarding the comment:

> i was thinking `set_fact` makes vars as hostvars which don't have precedence over playbook vars

Variables assigned through a `set_fact` module are in their own class of variables which has a lower priority only to block vars, task vars and extra vars. See [Variable Precedence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Comment: i was thinking set_fact makes vars as hostvars which don't have precedence over playbook vars

Comment: new link for variable precedence: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#ansible-variable-precedence

Comment: Totally useless answer as it doesn't actually change anything.